# Angular Fire fetching related data from same collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire5

I´m facing a strange behavior with a query on my firestore project. One user of the project is like the owner of the system, we call him the producer. And the other `users`, can belong to one `producer`, so I have a collection of `users`, where I have a field called `producer`, with the `producer ID`, like below.

```
{user: {id: '...', producer: '...', ...}
```

[image]
**Translate producer to produtor.*

I have a functionality called a transfer, where I can transfer cash from one user account to another, but only within the users of the same producer. So I need to fetch all the users where the producer is the same as the logged user, on this collection, here is my function:

```
constructor(
  private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private afs: AngularFirestore
) { }

fetchUsers() {
  return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap( user => { // Here I have the logged user
      return this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges() // Here I need his details on users collection
    }),
    first(),
    switchMap( (user: any) => {
      return this.afs.collection('users',
        ref => ref.where('producer', '==', user.producer) // Now I want the other users from same producer
      ).valueChanges()
    })
  )
}
```

But it does not work, the only user on the result is the user calling the function. Is it a limitation of the Angular Fire or maybe I´m doing it in the wrong way?

I think it´s maybe a bug, because I could workaround this using get on document and then on collection:

```
return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
            switchMap( user => {
                return this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).get()
            }),
            first(),
            map( usuario => {
                return usuario.data()
            }),
            switchMap( (usuario: any) => {
                return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('produtor', '==', usuario.produtor)).get()
            }),
            first(),
            map( data => {
                let users = []
                data.docs.map( doc => {
                    users.push(doc.data())
                })
                return users
            })
       )
```

This way, it returns all the users where the producer, *produtor*, is the same of logged in user. I´ll appreciate if someone could explain me why.

Comment: Can you please show your database structure? My assumption is that you aren't querying the correct data hence not getting the _users_ under a certain _producer_. If your data looks something like this: producers -> producer -> users -> user {id and producerField}, you may need to query the _producers_ collection to retrieve the correct _producer_ document, which will give you access to its list of _users_.

Comment: @sllopis i just added my data structure, I putted two records, one with UID starting with '06' is the producer, and the other users are related to him, in the field `produtor`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your OR query logic is incorrect.

```
return this.afs.collection('users',
        ref => ref.where('producer', 'in', [user.producer, user.uid]) 
).valueChanges()
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

In fact it appears you do not need an OR condition at all. Why would `user.producer` be set to two different types?

ie: if `user.producer` is always set to a producer ID, then you can have just:

```
return this.afs.collection('users',
            ref => ref.where('producer', '==', user.uid) 
    ).valueChanges()
```

Comment: Actually this `OR` condition was because the user logged could be the producer itself, then the field `producer`wouldn´t exists is this document, but, I´d chang it, and putted the field there to test. But it keeps returning only one record on query, the logged user.

Answer (score 0):

When you call .valueChanges() in Angular Fire, it returns an observable.

> Observables open up a continuous channel of communication in which multiple values of data can be emitted over time.

So we need to get a value from an Observable and for that we need to subscribe to it.
You could call the document with for valueChanges and attach a pipe(take(1)) as following, but get() is pretty handy.

```
   this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges()
   .pipe(take(1))
   .subscribe(v => {
       console.log(v);
    });
```

Please let me know if you need any further clarification.